# What exactly is Port Listening

Tags: network-programming, listener, port

Does "Listening" a port means a continuous polling to that port or a discrete polling or an interrupt driven process.
What exactly is going on in "Listening to a Port"?

Comment: this is from programmers.stackexchange [how-a-port-listens-pull-or-push]
describes in deep. 

  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/107545/36957

Comment: The answer describes the very low level mechanisms, below the notions of *tcp/udp*, *ports* and even *listening*, it's true for any network data reception.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *port* is nothing more than **a concept**, it's not like if you could check some memory bits, waiting for some information.

So, *listening* to a port will **teach the kernel what to do upon receiving packets with this specific port number**: transmit it to the process which asked to listen on that port, instead of replying [or not] that the port in not open.

NB: that's just speculations, I didn't investigate any kernel implementation.

**EDIT:** On the process side,

- [`listen`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) will tell the kernel that you're interested in a particular *rendez-vous port*
- (I'm not sure what happens between `listen` and `accept`, either the kernel buffers the new connections or rejects them until `accept` has been called, please refer to the relevant manual)
- [`accept`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) will bind the connection to a *communication port*, and start buffering the incoming packets
- [`recv`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) (or `poll` or `select` certainly) will pickup data from the reception buffer

Comment: that means Kernel will interrupt(notify) the process when this packet is received.

Answer (score 7):

The kernel extracts the destination port from incoming IP-packets and then forwards the packet to all receivers, that registered for this specific port (yes, there may be multiple). A user process normally uses select(2) or poll(2) to wait for an event, but this poll is different from the traditional polling like "read I/O port; delay 500 ms".